# python ctype initialising a structure

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

My structure contains all unsigned char elements

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char bE;
    unsigned char cH;
    unsigned char cL;
    unsigned char EId1;
    unsigned char EId0;
    unsigned char SId1;
    unsigned char SId0;
    unsigned char DLC;
    unsigned char D0;
    unsigned char D1;
    unsigned char D2;
    unsigned char D3;
    unsigned char D4;
    unsigned char D5;
    unsigned char D6;
    unsigned char D7;
 } CMsg;
```

The below function calls the structure

```
extern  int  WriteCMessage(HANDLE hDev,CMsg* pMsg);
```

I converted this structure to python ctype

```
class CMsg(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('bE', c_char),
               ('cH', c_char),
               ('cL', c_char),
               ('EId1', c_char),
               ('EId0', c_char),
               ('SId1', c_char),
               ('SId0', c_char),
               ('DLC', c_char),
               ('D0', c_char),
               ('D1', c_char),
               ('D2', c_char),
               ('D3', c_char),
               ('D4', c_char),
               ('D5', c_char),
               ('D6', c_char),
               ('D7', c_char)]
pmsg = CMsg('\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00','\x00')
```

Then i loaded the dll file

```
hllDll.WriteCANMessage(handle, pmsg)
```

But this gives error

> Error: Access violation at 0x00000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed `pmsg` by value, but the function expects a pointer. Since you've initialized to all zeros, the function ends up dereferencing a `NULL` pointer. Then ctypes uses Windows SEH to route the access violation to a Python exception.

You need to use `byref(pmsg)` to pass a reference. Also, define the function's `argtypes` to ensure proper handling of the pointer on 64-bit systems.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

class CMsg(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('bE', c_ubyte),
        ('cH', c_ubyte),
        ('cL', c_ubyte),
        ('EId1', c_ubyte),
        ('EId0', c_ubyte),
        ('SId1', c_ubyte),
        ('SId0', c_ubyte),
        ('DLC', c_ubyte),
        ('D0', c_ubyte),
        ('D1', c_ubyte),
        ('D2', c_ubyte),
        ('D3', c_ubyte),
        ('D4', c_ubyte),
        ('D5', c_ubyte),
        ('D6', c_ubyte),
        ('D7', c_ubyte)]

hllDll = cdll...
hllDll.WriteCANMessage.argtypes = [HANDLE, POINTER(CMsg)]

handle = ...
pmsg = CMsg() #  initially memset to {0}
hllDll.WriteCANMessage(handle, byref(pmsg))
```

Comment: But this method closes the python program says python.exe encountered a problem and need to close

Comment: That's a new problem. You'll have to add more context to the question.

Comment: Sorry i missed one point now only found that unsigned char *plBuf = (unsigned char *)&pmsg; How can i include this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Please update your question with details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: How can i add python ctype for this expression unsigned char *plBuf = (unsigned char *)&pmsg;

Comment: In `WriteCANMessage` (or is it `WriteCMessage`?), the variable `pMsg` (or `pmsg`?) is already a pointer to the buffer, so why would you cast `&pmsg`? That's the address of the pointer.

Comment: in linux am getting this error `hll.WriteCANMessage.argtypes = [handle, POINTER(CMsg)]
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ has no from_param method`

Comment: This question is tagged "windows" for a problem with a Windows access violation and a function that uses a Windows `HANDLE` type. `wintypes` isn't for Linux. Secondly, `handle` is clearly not a ctypes data type or a type with a custom `from_param` `classmethod`. Ask another question if you've switched to using a .so shared library on Linux.