# How to add a data call back using python ctype

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

How to implement a data callback using python ctypes

In C the data call back is like this

```
typedef int (*DATA_CALLBACK)(CMsg *pMsg, int *NumMsg)
```

How can i implement this call back in python

The CMsg is a structure as described in this thread

[python ctype intialising a structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799270/python-ctype-intialising-a-structure)

Comment: If the issue is how to read the C code and translate it to ctypes code, you may try cffi instead (http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: The ctypes docs explain how to implement [callback functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes#callback-functions). Work through the example. Use `libc = cdll.msvcrt`. Remember to keep a reference to the callback. Then if you're still having trouble implementing the `DATA_CALLBACK`, edit your question to include what you've tried.

Comment: refering to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799270/python-ctype-intialising-a-structure.....  how can i write above callback