# _argtypes_ has no from_param method

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

With respect to this question
[python ctype intialising a structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799270/python-ctype-intialising-a-structure/20799692?noredirect=1#comment31500898_20799692)

The above solutions woked fine for me in windows now i tried the same code in linux by loading a shared library,now i am getting this error

```
libCAN.WriteCANMessage.argtypes = [handle, POINTER(CMsg)]
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ has no from_param method
```

What should i do to eliminate this erro, i saw some links saying add `from_param classmethod` how to implement this in structure

Comment: It worked but i didnt understand how it worked?In my c program handle is int @eryksun

Comment: in windows i declared handle=c_int()` but it failed in linux then just like you said i wrote `handle=c_void_p` this worked both on linux and windows.How did that happen?In actual c program handle is defined like this `typedef int HANDLE;` @eryksun

Comment: Shouldn't you have a library function that opens the device/connection and returns a handle? In that case it would be `handle = libCAN.SOME_OPENER(*args)`, where  `SOME_OPENER.restype = c_int`.